# Explanation of the various Order Status for NopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

What are the meanings of the following order statuses (in terms of business process, not from `c#` point of view)? When each of them are used? Can anyone help me with this? I'm totally new to NOP Commerece. I didn't find any explanation of them.

```
public enum OrderStatus : int
{

    Pending = 10,     
    Processing = 20,
    SentToFullfillment = 25,
    Complete = 30,
    Cancelled = 40,
    FullfillmentError = 50,
    ShippingError = 60,
}
```

Comment: Are you using nopCommerce 3.80?

Comment: Yes I'm using 3.80

Comment: I could not found anywhere this enum in Nop, can you please provide a  path.

Comment: It is located at \Libraries\Nop.Core\Domain\Orders\OrderStatus.cs

Comment: Strange, in my code it looks like [this](http://imgr.es/3D0T)

Comment: My apology.. I inherited the system. I downloaded source code from NoComm website. It is similar to yours. So the system I've was modified from original source code. I can mark as answer if you want.

Comment: Alright, it happens some times :) I'll add my answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual code of `OrderStatus` is:

```
public enum OrderStatus
{  
   Pending = 10,

   Processing = 20,

   Complete = 30,

   Cancelled = 40
}
```

In business term, *Pending* means the order placed by customer. Once the order in process to shipping, the status change to *Processing*.

After delivered the order to the customer, store owner mark that order as *Complete*.

And if customer cancel the order then order status would be *Cancelled*.